# How do I cause instanced collections to rotate at different rates (using a driver)?

Tags: drivers, instances

I'm working in Blender 3.5 and sort of reacclimating myself to the new stuff after being away for more than a year.

I have a developed set of air conditioners and spinning fans. I have created separate instances of each housing and fan and instanced them. Now I want my fans to rotate - at different rates - on the Y axis.

Originally, I had my scene set up so that there was a fan in a hidden collection which was using a driver on the Y axis (frame/5). My main instances were (using a constaint) copying the rotation of that mesh. This way, I can adjust those instances' influence and make sure each fan is spinning at slightly different rates.

However, the result was hitchy animation. Doing some research, I learned that switching to quaternion can help that since frame interpolation is more accurate. However, when I did *that* I could no longer use the drivers.

So now I've gone simple. I have my instanced fans and I have added rotation drivers to them but the rotation is flatly not working.

I realize that I can manually animate this crap, but I'm trying to keep this non-keyframe since it's just spinning fans. I'm sure there's a way to do it but I'm rusty.

Thanks, in advance, for your help. Let me know if I can provide more specific data to elucidate my problem better.

It dawns on me that I might be able to use Geo Nodes to achieve this, so I will investigate that next.